# Help with an easy tikzpicture (mathematical proof)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, circles

I'm completely lost trying to make this (I guess) rather easy picture. Any help would be greatly appreciated[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,circle,minimum width=2cm] at (0,0) (A) {};
        \node[above] at (A.north) {$A$};
        \draw (A.west) -- (A.east);
        \path (A.center) -- node{$A-T$} (A.north);
        \path (A.center) -- node{$T$} (A.south);

        \node[draw,circle,minimum width=2cm] at (4,0) (B) {};
        \node[above] at (B.north) {$B$};
        \draw (B.west) -- (B.east);
        \path (B.center) -- node{$B-f(T)$} (B.north);
        \path (B.center) -- node{$f(T)$} (B.south);

        \draw[>=latex,->] (B.north west) to [in=20,out=160] node[above] {$g$} (A.north east);
        \draw[>=latex,->] (A.south east) to [in=200,out=340] node[below] {$f$} (B.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** arrows start and end inside circles and arrowheads are now in the middle

By using the `calc` library it is possible to calculate start (and end) positions for the arrows. For example `($(B.north east)!.8!(B.north west)$)` means: start the arrow at 80% in between `(B.north east)` and `(B.north west)`

Using the `decorations.markings` library makes it possible to change the position of the arrowhead.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,circle,minimum width=2cm] at (0,0) (A) {};
        \node[above] at (A.north) {$A$};
        \draw (A.west) -- (A.east);
        \path (A.center) -- node{$A-T$} ($(A.north)!.3!(A.center)$);
        \path (A.center) -- node{$T$} ($(A.south)!.3!(A.center)$);

        \node[draw,circle,minimum width=2cm] at (4,0) (B) {};
        \node[above] at (B.north) {$B$};
        \draw (B.west) -- (B.east);
        \path (B.center) -- node{$B-f(T)$} ($(B.north)!.3!(B.center)$);
        \path (B.center) -- node{$f(T)$} ($(B.south)!.3!(B.center)$);

        \draw[>=latex,->-=.5] ($(B.north east)!.8!(B.north west)$) to [in=20,out=160] node[above] {$g$} ($(A.north east)!.2!(A.north west)$);
        \draw[>=latex,->-=.5] ($(A.south east)!.2!(A.south west)$) to [in=200,out=340] node[below] {$f$} ($(B.south west)!.2!(B.south east)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Awesome! Thanks mate. Is there any way to get the arrows to enter the circles just a bit, and to move the "triangle part" of the arrows to the middle of that node?

Comment: @DagAndréen It sure is possible. Check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

With use of Ti*k*Z, this could look like the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{%
    ,mynode/.style={circle split,draw, minimum size=2.05cm,text height=\heightof{$f$},text depth=\depthof{g}}
    ,->-/.style={%
        decoration={%
            ,markings
            ,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}}
        ,postaction={decorate}
        ,shorten >=-3pt,shorten <=-3pt
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mynode,label=90:$A$] (Anode) {$A-T$ \nodepart{lower} $\vphantom{f(}T$};   
    \node [mynode,label=90:$B$,right = of Anode] (Bnode) {$B-f(T)$ \nodepart{lower} $f(T)$};    
    \draw[->-=.53] (Anode) to [bend right=20] node[below]{$f$} (Bnode);
    \draw[->-=.53] (Bnode) to [bend right=20] node[above]{$g$} (Anode);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1; you could avoid explicitly adding `A` and `B` as nodes using instead the `label` option for `Anode` and `Bnode`, like so: `\node [mynode,label=90:A] (Anode) {$A-T$ \nodepart{lower} $T$};`

Comment: @PierPaolo Thank you. This did not work as I was using the negative outer sep for the overlapping arrow lines. I changed the whole thing to a shortening approach and adapted to your recommendation. Much nicer code indeed.

Comment: It's weird. When I put this in my document, one circle end up smaller than the other

Comment: @DagAndréen Hmmm, I guess, you are using some font redefinitions then. Hard to tell as you have not given us an MWE. Easiest fix: Increase `minimum size=2.05cm` until it fits for you.